# Inno setup load string, get the number and add

Tags: inno-setup

I need the inno setup to take a line, check the number of Area. and add +1, see the example below

```
Original FILE:

[Area.1]
Title=World P1
Local=C:\scenery\world\p
Layer=
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE

[Area.2]
Title=World C1
Local=C:\scenery\world\c
Layer=
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE

[Area.3]
Title=World D1
Local=C:\scenery\world\d
Layer=
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE

[Area.4]
Title=World E1
Local=C:\scenery\world\e
Layer=
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE
```

Inno setup will check which is the last Area, in the case Area.4, it will take the number and add it with +1 and add one more area with the additional number to be able to follow the file as said.
So, take Area.4 and add

> [Area.5]
>
> Title=World F1
>
> Local=C:\scenery\world\f
>
> Layer=
>
> Active=TRUE
>
> Required=FALSE

Inno Setup, read and check last area, after install, it will stay like this

```
[Area.1]
Title=World P1
Local=C:\scenery\world\p
Layer=
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE

[Area.2]
Title=World C1
Local=C:\scenery\world\c
Layer=
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE

[Area.3]
Title=World D1
Local=C:\scenery\world\d
Layer=
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE

[Area.4]
Title=World E1
Local=C:\scenery\world\e
Layer=
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE

[Area.5]
Title=World F1
Local=C:\scenery\world\f
Layer=
Active=TRUE
Required=FALSE
```

I'm using this code, but it just adds, I need the installer to check the number in the original file and change the lines [1] adding +1, as if it were a sum in PHP / mysql

```
function saveStringToFile(): boolean;
var
  InstallDir: string;
  fileName : string;
  lines : TArrayOfString;
begin
  if FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\scenery.cfg')) then
  begin
    MsgBox('Archive "scenery.cfg" found', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := True;
    fileName := ExpandConstant('{app}\scenery.cfg');
    SetArrayLength(lines, 43);
  //
  lines[0] := '';
  lines[1] := '[Area.5]';
  lines[2] := 'Title=World F1';
  lines[3] := 'Local=C:\scenery\world\f';
  lines[4] := 'Layer=';
  lines[5] := 'Active=TRUE';
  lines[6] := 'Required=FALSE';
  lines[7] := '';
  //
  Result := SaveStringsToFile(filename,lines,true);
  exit;
  end
  else
  begin
    MsgBox('Archive "scenery.cfg" not found', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What does it mean *"add the number to +1"*? Do you want to change `[Area.1]` to `Area.2` and `Area.2` to `Area.3`? Would you show us the original file and how do you want it to look after the installation?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I think he wants to update the INI and add a new Area section with the next number. I think ...

Comment: You mention `[Area.X]`: Does it mean, you have a big file with some areas and you have to search for the area where Title=X, get its number, and add 1 to it?

Comment: I have a .cfg file that contains [Area.1] and its lines, I need Inno Setup to check the area number and add 6 more Areas, there would be Area.1,2,3,4,5, 6...
Just like @M.Bauer said

Comment: I edited the post to make it more understandable

Comment: This is not a code writing service. This question is way too specific to be helpful to anyone but you. Try to split your question into more questions, with each being generic enough to be helpful to others. I suggest you start with a question like *"How to find a section in an INI file with highest sequence number in Inno Setup?"*

Answer (score 0):

You first have to read the config file to get the maximum area number. See the following functions. There's a separate function to get out the number of a certain line. After you have the maximum number, you just have to add 1, and continue to write your aditional areas.

After you have your `fileName`, you can call:
`maxNumber := GetMaxNumber(fileName);`

The function have some explainig comments. There are also message boxes you can uncomment which give you some information what's going on.

```
function GetAreaNumber(line : String) : Integer;
var
    pos1, pos2 : Integer;
    number : String;
begin
    // This function only gets called, when the line contains an area header.
    // Get the positions of the chracter before and after the number and
    // extract the number.
    pos1 := Pos('.', line)
    pos2 := Pos(']', line)
    number := Copy(line, pos1 + 1, pos2 - (pos1 + 1))
    //MsgBox(number, mbInformation, MB_OK)
    Result := StrToIntDef(number, 0)
end;

function GetMaxNumber(fileName : String): Integer;
var
    lines : TArrayOfString;
    linesCount, index : Integer;
    maxNumber, currentNumber : Integer;
begin
    maxNumber := 0

    if LoadStringsFromFile(fileName, lines) then
    begin
        linesCount := GetArrayLength(lines)
        //MsgBox(IntToStr(linesCount), mbInformation, MB_OK)

        // Run through all the lines from the file.
        for index := 0 to linesCount - 1 do
        begin
            // Check if the line contains an area header.
            if Pos('[Area.', lines[index]) > 0 then
            begin
                //MsgBox(lines[index], mbInformation, MB_OK)
                currentNumber := GetAreaNumber(lines[index])

                if currentNumber > maxNumber then
                begin
                    maxNumber := currentNumber
                end
            end
        end
    end;

    Result := maxNumber
end;
```

Comment: Good. Use `StrToIntDef` to handle unexpected sections gracefully. Otherwise the installer will fatally fail when encountering lines like `[Area.]`, `[Area.X]`, etc. + You should test if the line starts with `[Area.`, not if it contains that only. The line can be commented out like `;[Area.1]`.

Comment: It would be worth considering using `IniKeyExists` in a loop to incrementally test for a section existence. That would be the most robust way.

Comment: I changed the string conversion function to `StrToIntDef()` as Martin suggested.

Comment: @Martin: Using `IniKeyExists` would require to know the smallest area number with which to start. If `[Area.2]` ist the first in the file, searching for `[Area.1]` will fail, and give you the wrong result.

Comment: Sure, that's what I mean by *"in a loop to incrementally test for a section existence"*